# Measuring site load times after user is logged in?

Tags: load-time, measure

How can I test my site "as if" users have logged in and then accessing different parts of the website?

I saw [Is there a good way to measure my site's response time from different parts of the world?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128/is-there-a-good-way-to-measure-my-sites-response-time-from-different-parts-of-th) but it looks like its just for a "outside" / publicly visible page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same concept except you need to use software capable of handling logins. Or, you can disable authentication for that user agent during testing.

Comment: Right... are there sites/services which do this? Or freeware/open-source toolkits which do this? What do you use? And we need to replicate basic user behavior after logging in, making changes to the site wont work.

Comment: sorry, could you lend some insight into this?

Comment: Setup a copy of your site and turn of the authentication system. Then run your tests. Unless your authentication system is horribly written this will allow you to test you pages that are behind logins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free iMacros browser addons and time the macro runtime with the STOPWATCH command: http://wiki.imacros.net/STOPWATCH (= web performance testing)

Answer (score -2):

When some user login, you save this time in some variables. Once he had a login, in jquery ready() sent the current time to your some PHP or JSP page(whatever you have). subtract both times.

This is just a concept only. I have not tried it before.